# Android random string doesn't check

Tags: android

Random string works fine.

Doesn't work check now.
I enter the text to what has been EditText drawn.

But the check is not working. Why?
Code:

```
    public static StringBuffer random() {
        String str = new String(
                "G12HIJdefgPQRSTUVWXYZabc56hijklmnopqAB78CDEF0KLMNO3rstu4vwxyz9");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.toString();
        String ar = null;
        Random r = new Random();
        int te = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            te = r.nextInt(62);
            ar = ar + str.charAt(te);
            sb.append(str.charAt(te));
        }
        return sb;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        random = random().toString();
        TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        display.setText("Random Number: " + random); // Show the random number
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumbers);
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            charsEntered = et.getText().toString();
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            Toast.makeText(et.getContext(), "Bla bla bla", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        if (random == charsEntered) {
            Toast.makeText(et.getContext(), "Good!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(et.getContext(), "Bad!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your Question More ?

Comment: Just doesn't work check.

Comment: Defus, if possible, please ensure code is posted _here_ rather than on sites like pastebin. That way, the questions remain useful even if other sites disappear totally. And, FYI, "just doesn't work" is not that useful a bug report. perhaps you could elaborate on what _does_ happen.

Comment: I know, but sometimes it does not work and it says that the post does not meet the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.equals` instead of `==`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (random.equalsIgnoreCase(charsEntered))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare two strings with the `==` operator. This cannot compare strings until Java 7, and Android is based on Java 6. Try using:

```
if (random.equalsIgnoreCase(charsEntered))
```

If the check is case insensitive or

```
if (random.equals(charsEntered))
```

If the check is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `StringBuffer` Class with `String` Class, try following,

```
    if ( random.toString().equals(charsEntered) )
    {
        Toast.makeText(et.getContext(), "Good!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(et.getContext(), "Bad!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```